# Query regarding .NET Reflection support in .NET Core

Tags: .net-core

We were porting a .NET 4.0 class Library to .NET Core 1.1 and struck an issue of limited support for .NET Reflection in the .NET Core CLR.

Can anyone help us with any details related to the .net core equivalent for calling `Type.GetProperties` and `Type.GetCustomAttributes` methods on an assembly object?

```
 Using System.Type;
 Type myType;   
    var prop = myType.GetProperties();
    var attrib = myType.GetCustomAttributes(true);
```

We can see there is `CustomAttributes` property, but this doesn't return instances of the custom attributes, but rather metadata about the attributes.

Comment: Call `Type.GetTypeInfo` first.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to use `GetTypeInfo` like this:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

Type myType = ...;   
TypeInfo myTypeInfo = myType.GetTypeInfo();

var prop = myTypeInfo.GetProperties();
var attrib = myTypeInfo.GetCustomAttributes(true);
```

When .NET Standard 2.0 and .NET Core 2.0 arrive, my understanding is that you won't need to make this change and can use the original APIs.

Comment: As an addendum, this document, titled "Porting to .NET Core" explicitly states the changes to `System.Type` and to do what you're recommending: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/02/10/porting-to-net-core/